# Is it possible to only allow some branches to trigger Github actions?

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

I was wondering if there were a way to restrict the branches that can trigger an action. Here is my use case.

I have a repository that have a workflow. This workflow deploys the code to my prod when there's a push on master only with the deploy_to_prod action. Someone decides to create a develop branch. He pushes on this branch a modification of the workflow to trigger the workflow anytime someone pushes to master or develop. It means he is now able to push develop on the prod environment without restriction and thus a branch protection on master is useless.

Am I missing something ? Do you have some mitigations policy to avoid this situation ? I have thought about restricting the branches that could trigger a workflow but I am not sure it would be sufficient and or possible.

- Can we protect the modification of workflows without having been merged to master for example ?
- Could we add a notification policy when those files are changed ?
- Could we restrict some runners to some branches (runners that have specific rights) ?

Thanks

Comment: I just answered... and deleted my answer! It's easy to say in an action what branches it applies to, but it's also easy for someone to push a change on some other branch that activates the workflow. You're raising a very interesting security question here in the GitHub Actions workflow system.

Comment: That means that giving someone write access to your repo, even with branch protection, requires trusting them not to misuse your repo. I think your best protection might be that only trusted contributors can be collaborators, while unknown contributors are required to submit their PRs from forks.

Comment: I've also been a bit uncomfortable with actions for a while: a devious collaborator could create an action that does `echo ${{ secrets.MY_SECRET }}`, push it to a dev branch and make it run. Then in the CI logs, the world can now see that secret. Sure, that leaves a trace, I'll know who did it, but it still bothers me how easy it would be to do it. Which brings us right back to your question.

Comment: Ah! Of interest: there are security settings associated with actions: https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/managing-your-repositorys-settings-and-features/enabling-features-for-your-repository/managing-github-actions-settings-for-a-repository But reading through this, it looks like you can prevent forked contributors from running your action via a PR, but I don't see a setting to prevent a collaborator with write access from running actions in any branch.

Comment: An option to avoid the problem you stated is to use [manual approval with Github Actions](https://trstringer.com/github-actions-manual-approval/#:~:text=Introducing%20the%20manual%2Dapproval%20GitHub%20Action!&text=manual%2Dapproval%20will%20create%20a,%2C%20%E2%80%9CLGTM!%E2%80%9D) for deploy in PROD. That way, even with a duplicated workflow which trigger on different conditions, the deploy wouldn't occur without authorization. [Reference on the Github Doc](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/managing-workflow-runs/reviewing-deployments)

Comment: Couldn't the malicious actor just remove the manual approval step? I believe the only way to make sure a malicious internal user cannot print the secret is to use [environment secrets](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/targeting-different-environments/using-environments-for-deployment#environment-secrets) in combination with protected environment as linked in the prev comment.

Comment: He can always remove the approval step even with environment secrets if I understood well (and print them, with a simple docker/entrypoint)

Comment: And regarding giving access to only trusted contributors I agree, but the internal fraud is a question in itself and if there's no way to mitigate it, it means the branch protection are useless. Maybe there is an alert policy that could be set up if the .github files are changed ?

Comment: I may be mistaken, but I think if the malicious user only has collaborator privileges, but not administrator privileges, they should not be able to remove the manual approval step.

Comment: but they can create another workflow that prints the secret without. As they can push code on their branch if they are contributors